# Skipping first value in the forloop

Tags: javascript, asp.net, for-loop, skip, continue

I have a forloop in javascript, which has 120 values, what i want is, i always want to skip the first values which the loop holds and always want to jump to next value which loop will generate, as i have several if conditions, value of `i` won't be always 0,1,2,3,4,5 etc.. it could be anything like 23,28,30,32 etc. below is my source code:
Have a look at the last line of the loop.

```
for (i = 0; i < document.links.length; i++) {
    L = document.links[i];
    ext = (L.href.indexOf('?') == -1) ? L.href.slice(-4).toLowerCase() : L.href.substring(0, L.href.indexOf('?')).slice(-4).toLowerCase();
    if (ext != '.jpg' && ext != '.png' && ext != '.gif' && ext != 'jpeg') continue;
    if (a == 'sh' && L.className.toLowerCase().indexOf('shutter') == -1) continue;
    if (a == 'lb' && L.rel.toLowerCase().indexOf('lightbox') == -1) continue;
    if (L.className.toLowerCase().indexOf('shutterset') != -1)
        setid = L.className.replace(/\s/g, '_');
    else if (L.rel.toLowerCase().indexOf('lightbox[') != -1)
        setid = L.rel.replace(/\s/g, '_');
    else setid = 0, inset = -1;
    if (setid) {
        if (!shutterSets[setid]) shutterSets[setid] = [];
        inset = shutterSets[setid].push(i);
    }
    imgdetails = L.innerHTML;
    console.log(imgdetails);
    img1 = jQuery.trim(imgdetails);
    alttext = jQuery(img1).attr('alt');
    shfile = L.href.slice(L.href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    T = (L.title && L.title != shfile) ? L.title : '';
    //alert(inset);
    shutterLinks[i] = {
        link: L.href,
        num: inset,
        set: setid,
        title: T,
        imagealt: alttext
    }
    //on below line, where i is being called i always want to skip the first value and always pass from second value.
    L.onclick = new Function('shutterReloaded.make("' + i + '");return false;');
}
```

Can anyone please help me with this.

Comment: A bit ambiguous in what you want done *exactly*.

Comment: The `continue` keyword can be used to skip one iteration of the loop. If you have logic that can detect whether to skip, you can use `continue;` like you would `break;` or `return;`.

Comment: `for (var i = 1; etc`?

Comment: @bfavaretto, I was thinking that as well. Not quite sure what the OP means by **"skip the first values"**

Comment: @NicholasV. I'm not sure either, just dropped that comment in case that's what the OP is looking for...

Answer (score 0):

Start with an index of 1 instead of 0 ("for (i = **1**; i < document.links.length; i++)"):

```
for (i = 1; i < document.links.length; i++) {
    L = document.links[i];
    ext = (L.href.indexOf('?') == -1) ? L.href.slice(-4).toLowerCase() : L.href.substring(0, L.href.indexOf('?')).slice(-4).toLowerCase();
    if (ext != '.jpg' && ext != '.png' && ext != '.gif' && ext != 'jpeg') continue;
    if (a == 'sh' && L.className.toLowerCase().indexOf('shutter') == -1) continue;
    if (a == 'lb' && L.rel.toLowerCase().indexOf('lightbox') == -1) continue;
    if (L.className.toLowerCase().indexOf('shutterset') != -1)
        setid = L.className.replace(/\s/g, '_');
    else if (L.rel.toLowerCase().indexOf('lightbox[') != -1)
        setid = L.rel.replace(/\s/g, '_');
    else setid = 0, inset = -1;
    if (setid) {
        if (!shutterSets[setid]) shutterSets[setid] = [];
        inset = shutterSets[setid].push(i);
    }
    imgdetails = L.innerHTML;
    console.log(imgdetails);
    img1 = jQuery.trim(imgdetails);
    alttext = jQuery(img1).attr('alt');
    shfile = L.href.slice(L.href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    T = (L.title && L.title != shfile) ? L.title : '';
    //alert(inset);
    shutterLinks[i] = {
        link: L.href,
        num: inset,
        set: setid,
        title: T,
        imagealt: alttext
    }
    //on below line, where i is being called i always want to skip the first value and always pass from second value.
    L.onclick = new Function('shutterReloaded.make("' + i + '");return false;');
}
```

Although, why you would need to do this is still unclear.